# Populating a binary search tree?

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a binary search tree from the following class:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

The following code should work on a list, cutting it in half and passing the halves off recursively. However, I'm getting the same node for both left and right.

```
def populatetree(words):#not working
   middle = len(words)//2
   root = Tree()
   root.data = wordlist[middle][0]

   if len(words) > 3:
      root.left = populatetree(words[:len(words)//2])
      root.right = populatetree(words[len(words)//2+1:])
   else:
      if middle!=0:
         root.left = Tree()
         root.left.data = words[0]
      if(len(words)==3):
         root.right = Tree()
         root.right.data = words[2]
   return root
```

Sample input:

```
['2', 'a', 'add', 'an', 'be', 'convert', 'integer', 'is', 'print', 'result', 'set', 'thank', 'the', 'to', 'variable', 'x1', 'y2', 'yes', 'you']'
```

Sample output:

```
['result']
['be', 'be']
['add', 'add', 'add', 'add']
['a', '2', 'a', '2', 'a', '2', 'a', '2']
['2', 'convert', 'set', 'x1']
```

where the output is being printed in a pyramidal format, in otherwords `be` and `be` belong to `result`, the first`add` and second `add` belong to be, and the next two `adds` belong to the other `be`, and so on and so forth. I've checked the actual data and `tree.left.data` and `tree.right.data` are in fact both `be` and `be`. This baffles me since the right sub tree shouldn't even be able to see `be` since I'm passing it the right half of the `list`.

Any idea what I need to do differently to populate the list properly?

Comment: What is "wordlist"?  How are you producing the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Tree.data is being taken from something called "wordlist", which is undefined within the sample code you presented, and is not the argument to the function populatetree.  Perhaps wordlist is the original list?

Comment: Good call, I accidentally hard coded that in before I chose to use a recursive function instead. That should be the 1d array `words`.

Comment: Since `wordlist` is the entire original list, it was only ever choosing from the first few of the original list instead of using separate lists for `right` and `left`